# opensearch autodiscover link not showing

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, opensearch

I have tried added the link tag in my head tag

```html
 <link rel="search" href="/opensearchdescription.xml" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="aaden001.cs518.cs.odu.edu" />
```

I have also created opensearchdescription.xml in root directory and it look like like this

```js
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>aaden001.cs</ShortName>
<Description>Use Google to search aaden001.cs</Description>
<Tags>aaden001.cs.odu.edu</Tags>
<Url type="text/html" template="http://aaden001.cs518.cs.odu.edu/?q= {searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

But I dont get the opensearch box in my website. Any help would be helpful